# Solve $7^x+x^4+47=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Solve $$7^x+x^4+47=y^2$$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{N}^*$

If $x$ is odd then the left term is congruent with $3$ mod $4$ so it couldn't be a perfect square, so we deduce that $x=2a$ and the relation becomes $$49^a+16a^4+47=y^2$$ and it is easy to see that the left term is divisible by $16$  so we obtain that $y=4b$, so we have to find $a$ and $b$ such that $$49^a+16a^4+47=16b^2$$From this point I was completely stuck. I think that there are no solutions but how can I prove it?

Comment: The next square after $(7^a)^2$ is probably more than the LHS

Comment: @Empy2 Yes you are right Sir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x$ is even and let $x=2a$, then $(7^a)^2<7^x+x^4+47<(7^a+1)^2=7^x+2\times7^a+1$ if $(2a)^4+47<2\times7^a+1$, which is true for $a \ge 4$. Therefore, it is enough to consider only $x=2, 4$ and $6$.

Comment: Yeap, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove no solutions.  $x=4, y=52$ is a solution.

Comment: Ok, so my thoughts were wrong. Still, how do we find all solutions?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to find all solutions. A computer check (using Python) gave no other solutions up to $x=1000$.

Comment: you have to check only a finte number of $x$. I think $100$ is enough

Answer (score 0):

When $x$ is odd then $7^x+x^4+47\equiv 3(\mod 4)$. So, it is not possible $y^2\equiv 3(\mod 4)$.

Let $x=2k$, then for $k\geq 4$

$$(7^k)^2<7^{2k}+(2k)^4+47<(7^k+1)^2$$

This mean we have $k\leq 3$.
if try to $k=1,2,3$ only $x=4$ is a solution.